# What is the best way to interface ST7066 lcd controller with Atmel SAM4E

Tags: microcontroller, atmel, character-lcd

I am trying to interface ST7066 LCD controller with Atmel SAM4E MCU, but is quite confused about the best way(Least no. of pins used) to interface them together. Should I use GPIOs or Should I go for Static memory controller. Do it needs any chip select or SPI.

Comment: What does it say in the data sheet?

Comment: Define best: Lowest code effort, lowest pin count, highest update rate, etc...

Comment: @ConnorWolf Best in terms of lowest pin count which also in-directly means lowest code effort.

Comment: @RoshanGupta - That is very much not true in many cases. For HD44780 LCD modules, 8 pin mode means simpler code. In general, big, simple parallel busses are easiest from a code perspective.

Comment: A general rule of thumb is that bus protocol complexity and programming complexity are **inversely** proportional. Hell, in a number of projects where I've had HD44780 LCDs (which are very similar to your LCD) and plenty of spare IO, I've chosen to use them in 8-bit mode because it was easier to debug and program for, so in your case, lower pin count is *specifically* more involved with regard to programming.

Comment: @ConnorWolf I agree with you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That controller, like many of its class, has an 8-bit and a 4-bit interface mode.  If you elect to use the 4-bit mode, you will use RS, R/W, E, DB4, DB5, DB6 and DB7 (7 pins total) to connect to the microprocessor.  If you use the 8-bit mode, it additionally uses DB0 through DB3 for a total of 11 pins. See [the datasheet](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/LCD/st7066.pdf) for details.

To further minimize the number of pins, you can wire RS and R/W low, but this means you can't read back from the controller.  Many simple projects that only use the built-in character generator can get away with this.

Typically, one uses GPIO pins for this kind of interface.

Comment: Thanks, I did the same before reading this answer,     your answer re-affirms my point.